# wordpress post first image

Tags: wordpress, filter

How would I filter my posts featured or first images in WordPress and before displaying add to theme a css class. I saw that I could use in my functions.php the add_filter() function from the API but I have problems to get each posts first image.

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/test.jpg">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-95" width="540" height="300" alt="dell-vs-apple" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/dell-vs-apple1.jpg">
</a>


<div class = "my_class">
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/dell-vs-apple1.jpg">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-95" width="540" height="300" alt="dell-vs-apple" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/dell-vs-apple1.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get the first image from post ..

```
  // Get URL of first image in a post
    function o99_find_first_post_image() {
        global $post, $posts;
        $first_img = '';
        ob_start();
        ob_end_clean();
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
        $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

        // if no image found we can choose to display some default image instead
        if(empty($first_img)){
            $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";// path to default image
        }
        return $first_img;
    }
```